# Converting Byte to byte[]

Tags: java, soap

Can anybody tell me how to convert `Byte` into `byte[]`.
I am getting `Byte` from web service call,From that wrapper type `Byte` I need to get `byte[]`, then from `byte[]` I need to get PDF.
So can anybody suggest me how to get `byte[]` out of wrapper type `Byte`.

Comment: I assume you don't mean just java.lang.Byte, i.e. a single byte of data. Please clarify.

Comment: You cannot go from `Byte` to a PDF unless that `Byte` represents a unique ID (of 256 possible values). Otherwise, as some answers are pointing out, a `byte` is the unboxed version of `Byte`, but that will not help you load a PDF from it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not quite comprehensible.

If you mean, that you have some `Byte` variable, then it will be:

```
Byte x ....  // is input variable
byte[] bArr = new byte[] { x.byteValue() };
```

If you mean, that you deal with `Byte[]` array and need to translate it into `byte[]` array, then it will be:

```
Byte[] x ... // is your Byte array
byte[] bArr = new byte[x.length];
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) bArr[i] = x[i].byteValue();
```